# UndocumentedApi rule bug in Sonar 4.3

Tags: sonarqube

I have the following code :

```
private Integer idadr;

@Id()
@SequenceGenerator(name = "idadrGenerator", sequenceName = "SEQ_ADR", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "idadrGenerator")
@Column(name = "IDADR", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 8)
public Integer getIdadr() {
  return this.idadr;
}

public void setIdadr(Integer idadr) {
  this.idadr = idadr;
}
```

When I run an analyse :  a new violation with the UndocumentApi rule is raised.
I think this violation must not appear because it is a basic getter on a field.

Is it a bug ?

Regards,

Stef

Comment: Have you set "sonar.squid.analyse.property.accessors" to true ? See - http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Metrics+-+Public+API and http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/Undocumented-public-API-td5016952.html for where to set it.

Comment: yes, it is to true (default value)

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you get the violation if you remove 'this' from the getter (i.e. return idadr) ?

Comment: no, i remember that it war on old bug in sonar 3.6.x but I think it will be fixed in the new version :(

Comment: By th way i put a workaround : i use the exclusion pattern : squid:UndocumentedApi;src/main/java/fr/**/metier/**/* (all my entitirs with a lot of getters & setters are in the metier package)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not due to be fixed - 
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-7 . Feel free to add this as an answer so it's clear to anyone coming to this page later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your comment says, this is a bug/deficiency in how SonarQube decides if a method is a getter.

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-7

Unfortunately it's **not** currently going to be fixed because of a related ticket (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-398)

Comment: It's pity because it's add lot off false positive ... and the tool become less boring !